# Can't run simple go program contains cgo stuff

Tags: c, go, cgo

I'm trying to run the following simple go code with reference to simple C code (all files located  in the same folder):

**main.go**

```golang
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lib.h"
*/

import "C"
import "unsafe"

func Print(s string) {
                cs := C.CString(s)
                C.print_str(cs)
                C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cs))
}

func main() {
                str1 := "hi how are you\n"
                Print(str1)
}
```

The C code:

**lib.h**

```c
void print_str(char *s);
```

**lib.c**

```c
#include "stdio.h"
 
void print_str(char *s)
{
    printf("%s\n", s?s:"nil");
}
```

Tried to run `go build main.go`, both in Windows and Linux, with the latest version of go (1.16.5) and got:

```sh
# command-line-arguments
/tmp/go-build3048423534/b001/_x002.o: In function `_cgo_976ac389362d_Cfunc_print_str':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:61: undefined reference to `print_str'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't know which options you need but you are not adding `lib.c` to your build anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

First I compiled the shared lib
`gcc -fPIC -shared lib.c -o lib.so`

Then I added a reference to that .so in your go file
`#cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR} lib.so`
(Ref: https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/)

```
$ go run main.go
hi how are you
```

Final code:

```golang
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <lib.h>
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR} lib.so
*/
import "C"
import "unsafe"

func Print(s string) {
    cs := C.CString(s)
    C.print_str(cs)
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cs))
}

func main() {
    str1 := "hi how are you\n"
    Print(str1)
}
```